# Customised confirm jquery dialog across project

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have to create a confirm modal box of jquery that works as default confirm box that return true or false and works across the project.

I call it this way....

```
var result = confirm("Are you sure you want exit");
if(result == false)
     return false;
else{
    //somethings are done here
}
```

and in a Main.js written it's implementation as following ..

```
function confirm(message){
    $("#alert_cust_message").html(message);
    var returnValue = false;
    $("#myAlert").dialog({
        modal: true,
        minHeight: 100,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() 
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                returnValue = true;
            },
            Cancel: function() 
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                returnValue = false;
            }
        }
    });
    $("#myAlert").parent().css('font-size','9pt');
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now the problem that i am facing is about the return value ...

I am not get the expected returns, I think it is due to asynchronous dialog.

Now can this be solved easily ?

Any help will be appreciated .. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a callback

```
function confirm(message, callback) {
    $("#alert_cust_message").html(message);
    var returnValue = false;
    $("#myAlert").dialog({
        modal: true,
        minHeight: 100,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                callback(true);
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });

    $("#myAlert").parent().css('font-size', '9pt');
}
```

then

```
confirm('some message', function (result) {
    if (result) {}
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3N5Tj/)

Comment: can i avoid the callback part ?

I mean is there a way to do it without callback function?

Comment: @Saurabh not really... another solution is to use Defferred/promise

Comment: Thanks for the solution ....
the defferred.promise is a promising job .. so will go by this solution **thanks** again.